# Angular js do not scroll when list element height change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a list of elements. Each element has an expanded and collapsed state. 
When user expands one of the element, all other elements need to collapse. The list is inside a div which could be scrolled to allow seeing the entire list.

- element 1
- element 2
- element 3
- element 4
- element 5

Lets say, element 1 is in expanded state. When I expand element 3, I collapse element 1. The problem is that when I do that, element 3 scrolls up. I want to avoid this and position element 3 to same position.

This is a pseudo code. There could be some minor syntax errors, but do ignore them, since my actual code has lot more going on and I don't want to paste the entire thing here.

The controller will include expand function like:

```
public expandElement(currentElement: any, previousElement: any) {

 // get the height of previous element 
  var scrollOffset: number = angular.element("#" + this.getAnchorId(previousElement).offsetHeight;

  // this function will collapse the element decreasing the height of it
  previousElement.collapse();

  // scroll to the newly expanded element
  this.$timeout(() => {
    var anchorId: string = this.getAnchorId(element);
    var element = angular.element("#" + anchorId)[0];
    var offset = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollOffset;
    this.$anchorScroll.yOffset = offset;
    this.$location.hash(anchorId);
    this.$anchorScroll();
  });

   previousElement = currentElement;
}
```

The html will look something like:

```
 <div ng-repeat="element in listElements"
   id="{{getAnchorId(element)}}">

   <my-directive ng-click="expandElement(element, previousElement)"></my-directive>
   </div>
```

This currently is not working at all, **but even if I get it to work, there would be a small UI jump that could happen. I want to avoid scroll completely.**

Is there another easy way to just block the scroll when angular expands an element?

Appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to post your code :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem, but i have one question. Consider you have more elements in the list and you will expand say 50th element then it has to scroll the main container to show the content of that expanded panel, i think it is the desired functionality in the scroll. I know i am not answering your question but, just thought of reconsidering it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to save scroll position and after click function got triggered change the scroll position back to saved state. There could be flick effect. If you want to hide the flick effect, hide the div show with a slow animation. Hope it helps.